# ReSharper chop if long not working

Tags: resharper

I have the following code that when I run autoformat in ReSharper doesn't not get changed.

[image]

I thought Chop if long would cause a chop to occur if the right margin is exceeded.

If I turn on Chop always I get this.

[image]

This works, but I would rather not chop short statements like the first, which is what I assume Chop if long means.

Ideas?

Here are my ReSharper settings.

[image]

Turning on wrap long lines makes things even worse.

[image]

**UPDATE1:**

Here is the email I sent to JetBrains support.

The believe the central issues I'm facing is I understand the "chop always" setting, but I do not understand "chop if long" or "simple wrap". I have not found any documentation on what these settings mean, so I'm going off what I believe should be happening.

I am setting the "Wrap object collection and initializer".

Chop Always:

```
        cdata.GetByIdData = new Category {
            Id = "123",
            Name = "category"
        };
        vdata.GetByIdData = new Vendor {
            Id = "456",
            Name = "vendor"
        };
        adata.GetByIdData.Add(new Account {
            Id = "789",
            Name = "account",
            Balance = 5000
        });

        svc.ExecuteRequest(new AccountTransactionService.Add {
            Kind = AccountTransaction.KIND_DEBIT,
            Source = "789",
            Destination = "dst",
            Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
            Categories = new List<AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory> {
                new AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory {
                    Id = "123",
                    Amount = 200.50m
                }
            }
        });
```

Chop If Long:

```
        cdata.GetByIdData = new Category { Id = "123", Name = "category" };
        vdata.GetByIdData = new Vendor { Id = "456", Name = "vendor" };
        adata.GetByIdData.Add(new Account { Id = "789", Name = "account", Balance = 5000 });

        svc.ExecuteRequest(new AccountTransactionService.Add { Kind = AccountTransaction.KIND_DEBIT, Source = "789", Destination = "dst", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), Categories = new List<AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory> { new AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory { Id = "123", Amount = 200.50m } } });
```

I would expect Chop If Long to look like this given a margin of 80:

```
        cdata.GetByIdData = new Category { Id = "123", Name = "category" };
        vdata.GetByIdData = new Vendor { Id = "456", Name = "vendor" };
        adata.GetByIdData.Add(new Account { Id = "789", Name = "account", Balance = 5000 });

        svc.ExecuteRequest(new AccountTransactionService.Add {
            Kind = AccountTransaction.KIND_DEBIT,
            Source = "789",
            Destination = "dst",
            Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1),
            Categories = new List<AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory> {
                new AccountTransactionService.CreateCategory {
                    Id = "123",
                    Amount = 200.50m
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It would help if you make your sample code available as text and also provide an export of your code style settings (R# > Manage Options > Import/Export settings)

Answer (score 3):

"Chop if long" works only when you turn on "Wrap long lines" option, so you should turn it on. I guess that http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-291146 prevented you from getting the formatting you wanted with "Wrap long lines" turned on. Well, it should be fixed in ReSharper 7.1 EAP - try and write us if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change "Wrap object collection and initialisers" to "Simple Wrap", that should style your code in the way you want it to.

Unfortunately, I can't look up what Chop if long is supposed to do as the Resharper community site is blocked from work for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue logged with JetBrains that is depicting the same behavior you describe...

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-291146